# jQuery toggling checkboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, toggle

The Students Gridview has a Check All checkbox at the top and it controls the on/off of the checkboxes. I want to toggle checkboxes on and off in the Students Grid View.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chkAll").click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == "checked") {
            $("#<%= gvStudents.ClientID %> :checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", "checked");
        }
        else {
            $("#<%= gvStudents.ClientID %> :checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", "false");
        }    
    });    
});
```

It used to work in jQuery 1.4.xx but today I upgraded to JQuery 1.8.1 and it no longer works. What should I need to get it working again?

Comment: try using `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`

Comment: a few doubts... You want to check **all** the boxes or you just want to invert the selection?

Comment: try to use `.attr()` and `attr("checked", false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you should need:

```
$("#chkAll").click(function () {
    var checkAll = $(this).prop("checked");
    $("#<%= gvStudents.ClientID %> :checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", checkAll);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZfzS/

But to make this more intuative, you should probably uncheck the "checkAll" checkbox when one or more of the others are unchecked. This could be done with this addition:

```
$("#<%= gvStudents.ClientID %> :checkbox").not('#chkAll').click(function(){
    var total = $("#<%= gvStudents.ClientID %> :checkbox").not('#chkAll').size();
    var checked = $("#<%= gvStudents.ClientID %> :checkbox").not('#chkAll').filter(':checked').size();
    $("#chkAll").prop("checked",total == checked);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xV2ej/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your selector it looks like you're using the same `ID` for both the `checkboxes`.

Either give different `ID` or Use the `class` selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

This line return true or false, but not "checked", guess this is the reason

```
$(this).prop("checked")
```

to check/uncheck

```
$(this).prop("checked",true)  //check
$(this).prop("checked",false) //uncheck
```